# Problems with replacing a column value with lookup table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to replace column values with the ones defined in `lut`:

```
library("hflights")
library(dplyr)  # For tbl_df
hflights <- tbl_df(hflights)

glimpse(hflights)

lut <- c("AA" = "American", "AS" = "Alaska", "B6" = "JetBlue", "CO" = "Continental", "DL" = "Delta", "OO" = "SkyWest", "UA" = "United", "US" = "US_Airways", "WN" = "Southwest", "EV" = "Atlantic_Southeast", "F9" = "Frontier", "FL" = "AirTran", "MQ" = "American_Eagle", "XE" = "ExpressJet", "YV" = "Mesa")

carriers <- hflights$UniqueCarrier

carriers <- lut[carriers]

hflights$UniqueCarrier <- carriers

glimpse(hflights)

lut <- c ("A" = "carrier", "B" = "weather", "C" = "FFA", "D" = "security", "E" = "not cancelled")


cancellation <- hflights$CancellationCode
cancellation <- lut[cancellation]
hflights$CancellationCode <- cancellation

glimpse(hflights)
```

when I use `hflights <- tbl_df(hflights)`, both replacement operation fails and I get NA values for the corresponding columns, but when I don't use `tbl` from `dplyr` package, the first one is successful but for the second one I get NA values. `hflights`is package that contains Houston Flights Data. What's wrong with me? Sorry for my poor English!

Comment: most of the elements in `hflights$CancellationCode` are `""`, so they are not in your look-up table.

Comment: How to handle `""`? add `"" = ""` to the elements of `lut`?

Comment: You should add the E cancellation code to the data first. `hflights$CancellationCode[hflights$CancellationCode == ""] <- "E"`

Comment: I get this: Error in $<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "col03", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1481586.

Comment: @Amin: I followed Pierre's suggestion and got the expected result. "E" is now the value for 224523 rows. I did this before running your code so your test may need to be instead : `hflights$CancellationCode[ is.na(hflights$CancellationCode) ] <- "E"`